# How to specify the display used by cv2.imshow()

Tags: 18.04, python, opencv

Goal:
On a system with two displays and I want to specify the display used by the cv2.imshow command (python 3.6 with Ubuntu 18.04)

Here is what I have tried:

```
import os
import cv2


def f(display):
    os.environ['DISPLAY'] = display
    print(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
    a= cv2.imread('initializing.png')
    cv2.imshow('window', a)
    cv2.waitKey(100000)


f(':0.0') #Is this correct if the goal is the display labeled as 1 in settings?
```

If this is changed to f(':1.0') the window opens on display 2.  The goal is for the window to open on either display 2 or display 1.

Here is the error:

```
.py 
:0.0
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyUnable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(window:19529): Gtk-WARNING **: 10:51:10.537: cannot open display: :0.0
111
```

I have installed X with the following:

```
sudo apt-get install xorg openbox
```

What am I missing?  Any other ideas how accomplish the goal?

Comment: You say you "installed" xorg and openbox - but are you actually *running* an X session on the display? what is the output of `xauth list` ?

Comment: here is the output:
`FDBK-DEV-2/unix:  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  0ca4e0583a6f10ebc54b62bbb8d7f952
#ffff#4644424b2d4445562d32#:  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  0ca4e0583a6f10ebc54b62bbb8d7f952`

Comment: I found a work around by using cv2.namedWindow("window", WINDOW_NORMAL) and moving the open window mannualy.